# What's the difference between "e.g." and "ex."?

Tags: differences, abbreviations

`E.g.` is short for [exempli gratia](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e.g.), and is in common use to introduce an example within a sentence.

> Submit a sample of academic writing, e.g., a dissertation chapter.

However, some authors use `ex.` or `ex:` (short for "example") for the same purpose, and this form is listed in some authorities like the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex.#Noun).

> Submit a sample of academic writing, ex: a dissertation chapter.

I know they both roughly mean "example", but which one should I use, and when? Are there connotations associated with one or the other?

This question has been asked [elsewhere](https://www.quora.com/How-common-is-using-ex-as-the-short-for-example), and this very answer comes up when you ask Google about the difference. It would be good to get an EL&U answer for it.

Comment: I wish this were not considered off-topic. I assume it's because it can supposedly be answered using commonly available references. However, one value of this site to me is that it helps to measure the gradual change in acceptable usage. That gradual change eventually culminates in changes to commonly available references, but even before that happens, it would be useful to know if in some subcultures people are preferring "ex." over "e.g." . . . so please re-open this question for new answers.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*E.g.* is short for *exempli gratia* and stands for "for example". *Ex.*, if used to mean the same, is incorrect. Mostly *ex.* is used as short for *exercise* and not "for example".

Comment: "incorrect"? Per *who*?

Comment: @IonicBurger Your answer is utterly unfriendly and unacceptable.

Answer (score 20):

"Ex." is not very common, but it may be used to *refer* to a cited example, eg "See ex. 3".

"E.g." is much more common, and is used to introduce an example, or series of examples. In speech, it is usually replaced by "for example".

Comment: [Citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285) for "*may be used to refer to a **cited** example*..."